# CSS3 Transform Differences Between Angular 2 and Angular 7

Tags: css, angular, animation, transform

I recently migrated an inherited Angular 2 application to Angular 7.2.  There were a dozens of issues which needed resolution, but I'm down to one last question that relates to animation transforms.

The code below works just fine in the Angular 2 version of the application but throws runtime errors i the Angular 7 version.  This is true for Chrome and Safari browsers.  If I remark out the first 4 transform lines, the Angular 7 applcation runs without error (and the animation works!).

```
      state('*', style({
            '-ms-transform': 'translate3D(0px, 0px, 0px)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3D(0px, 0px, 0px)',
            '-moz-transform': 'translate3D(0px, 0px, 0px)',
            '-o-transform':'translate3D(0px, 0px, 0px)',
            transform:'translate3D(0px, 0px, 0px)',
            opacity: 1})),
```

The error message in Chrome is **Uncaught (in promise): Error: The animation trigger "cardphone" has failed to build due to the following errors: - The provided animation property "ms-transform" is not a supported CSS property for animations." This error is repeated for all four of the browser-specific transforms.

There are no compiler errors in either environment -- this is a runtime issue.

Can anyone shed light on the different behavior between Angular versions?

Comment: try enabling all polyfills in polyfill.ts file and try

Comment: Looks like you can use a [package config](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-autoprefixer) to augment the target browsers.

Comment: any solution for this?